# django-import-export not showing in admin

Tags: django, django-admin, django-import-export

I have a problem with django import-export tool. Simmilat to the one described in [This topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34792159/django-import-export-can-not-get-it-working). Problem is there is no solution for the problem posted there and I need it badly. Buttons for import/export in my admin panel do not show up. Did change the order of declaration, run collectstatic, restarted server ...

I could use your help django masters.

```
 from django.contrib import admin
    #from actions import export_to_csv
    from import_export import resources
    from import_export.admin import ImportExportModelAdmin, ImportExportMixin, ImportMixin, ExportActionModelAdmin, ImportExportActionModelAdmin
    from .models import Library
    from datetime import datetime
    from django import forms
    from redactor.widgets import RedactorEditor

     # registered models

    class LibraryResource(resources.ModelResource):

        class Meta:
            model = Library

    class LibraryAdmin(ImportExportModelAdmin, admin.ModelAdmin):
        resource_class = LibraryResource

        list_display = ...
        list_display_links = ...
        search_fields =...
        list_filter = ...


        def name(self, obj):
            return obj.library.name
            name.admin_order_field  = 'name'  #Allows column order sorting
            name.short_description = 'Biblioteka'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove , admin.ModelAdmin from this line and it should start working:
class LibraryAdmin(ImportExportModelAdmin, admin.ModelAdmin):

Comment: Gosh it took me long to confirm this. It works. I guess problem was in missconfigured static files on top of that error. Plus ... I broke my server on the way. Noob my. Thank you for the answer!

Answer (score 1):

1. After installing the **django-import-export** package using:

   **pip install django-import-export**
2. Within the **settings.py** file, add 'import_export' to the list of installed apps:

   INSTALLED_APPS = [
   ...
   'import_export'
   ...
   ]
3. Within the **admin.py** file, here is how to use the import_export package:

   from django.contrib import admin

   from import_export.admin import ImportExportModelAdmin

   from .models import Bot

   admin.site.register(Bot, ImportExportModelAdmin)

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was overriding Django admin list template:

```
{% extends "admin/change_list.html" %}

{% block object-tools-items %}
  {{ block.super }}

  <Code>
{% endblock %}
```

But in order for import_export buttons to appear, you need to override their template, so the first line should be:

```
{% extends "admin/import_export/change_list_import_export.html" %}
```